# Entity Framework 6 Stored Procedure C# side missing created column

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I have the following stored procedure. I implemented the UNION to avoid writing 2 stored procedures. My main issue is that EF will not recognize the dynamically created column, even if I add it manually to the object_result class that queries the model. Does anyone know how to get such dynamically generated columns to work?

(What's weird is the `RANK() VolumeRank` below does work. But `RefYear` does not map).

SQL:

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET FMTONLY OFF; 

    SELECT * 
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             B.OS, B.DS, COUNT(DISTINCT A.PO) Volume, 
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT A.PO) DESC) VolumeRank, 
             YEAR(GETDATE()) RefYear 
         FROM 
             DB.DW.LoadData AS A 
         JOIN 
             DB.DW.Geo AS B ON A.PO = B.PO 
         INNER JOIN 
             DW.DMaster AS C ON A.LoadDateKey = C.DateKey 
         WHERE  
             C.IsT12Weeks_LastWeek = 1 
             AND a.PrimaryCustomerID = @CustomerId
         GROUP BY 
             B.OS, B.DS) AS A 
    WHERE 
        VolumeRank <= 3 

    UNION

    SELECT * 
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             B.OS, B.DS, 
             COUNT(DISTINCT A.PO) Volume, 
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT A.PO) DESC) VolumeRank,
             YEAR(getdate())-1 RefYear 
         FROM 
             DB.DW.LoadData AS A 
         JOIN 
             DB.DW.Geo AS B ON A.PO = B.PO 
         INNER JOIN 
             DW.DMaster AS C ON A.LoadDateKey = C.DateKey 
         WHERE 
             PrimaryCustomerID = @CustomerId 
             AND FWeek >= @FirstWeek 
             AND FWeek <= @LastWeek 
             AND FiscalYear = @FiscalYear
         GROUP BY 
             B.OS, B.DS) AS A 
     WHERE 
         VolumeRank <= 3 
     ORDER BY 
         RefYear DESC, Volume DESC
END
```

C#:

```
List<spGetT_Result> result = new List<spGetT_Result>();

using (var db = new T_Entities())
{
    result = db.spGetT(eid, firstWeek, lastWeek, year).ToList();
}
```

Model class includes this line, but it's always null when I run:

```
public Nullable<int> RefYear { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you include the code from db.spGetT and the full spGetT_Result class? As a troubleshooting step you could try executing the sp via db.Database.SqlQuery<spGetT_Result>("whatever the sp is named", {parameterized conditions here})

Comment: I can't disclose the full class for business reasons, but it would at least contain the problem member:
`code`
    public partial class spGetT_Result
    {
        ...
        public Nullable<int> RefYear { get; set; }
    }
`code`
Parameters:
@CustomerId AS INT,
@FirstWeek AS INT,
@LastWeek AS INT,
@FiscalYear AS INT

I can do it the latter way you mentioned just weird EF does not permit the dynamic column being read it would seem.  Also, Ado.NET way works as well.  My boss at first preferred EF.  I have read somewhere that EF has issues with dynamically added columns in SPs.

Comment: I believe that the contents of the stored procedure are opaque to EF, it just deals with supplied parameters and a returned data set. It would have no knowledge if a column came from a data field or a function, it would only see the data type and the value. I would have to guess that the issue is somewhere in the spGetT method. YEAR returns an int, which would be fine with your int? I'd look again at spGetT. If you're using a database first model, refresh or delete and re-add the sp